# pycharm syntax check error for python 3 print end=" " but still works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am using `Pycharm 2018.3.4`. When `python 3` is used, it indicates error for the `end=""` in the `print` function.

However, the code could still be run without any problem. So how to remove the red line for syntax check?

(I feel `pycharm` gets more popularity in `stackoverflow` than `superuser`, so I asked the question here)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you might have it set to Python 2 syntax somehow.

Comment: No, if I set it to `python 2`, the code could not run because the syntax is `print 'test'` instead of `print('test').

Comment: @lanselibai I think they're saying that the PyCharm syntax-checker is set to Python 2.

Comment: okay, so how to change the syntax-checker?

Comment: Make sure Python 3 is selected in **Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter**.

Comment: yes, this is already selected. Otherwise, the code will not run. I think this selection is not for the syntax checker.

Answer (score -1):

Check your Interpreter's version is python 3.x in the right bottom of the pycharm, weather you are 3.x, You could try to retry the "InterpreterSetting" , this buttom.

I am not English speaker, I was left a comment by my language, but it was deleted by someone.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZK3F.png)

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok, I'm not good at English, I did used the Chinese to described it , but my Chinese comment is deleted by someone called EricAya, so, I don't want to say it again.